# Create an RDD with more elements than its source

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd, distributed-computing, bigdata

I have an RDD called `codes`, which is a pair, that has a string as its 1st half and another pair as its 2nd half:

```
In [76]: codes.collect()
Out[76]: 
[(u'3362336966', (6208, 5320)),
 (u'7889466042', (4140, 5268))]
```

and I am trying to get this:

```
In [76]: codes.collect()
Out[76]: 
[(u'3362336966', 6208),
 (u'3362336966', 5320),
 (u'7889466042', 4140),
 (u'7889466042', 5268)]
```

How to do this?

---

My failed attempt:

```
In [77]: codes_in = codes.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0]), (x[0], x[1][1]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-e1c7925bc075> in <module>()
----> 1 codes_in = codes.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0]), (x[0], x[1][1]))

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the following:

```
codes_in = codes.map(lambda x: [(x[0], p) for p in x[1]]).flatMap(lambda x: x)
```

If it is python 2, for legibility you could:

```
codes_in = codes.map(lambda k, vs: [(k, v) for v in vs]).flatMap(lambda x: x)
```

By this way you will be able to "extract" each value associated with the key and force that every row is a record of form `(k, v)`.